# Is there a specific name for polytopes that only have 0s and 1s as coordinates?

Tags: polytopes

I only know of the name 0/1-polytope, but whenever I search for it on Google, I get articles written by the same author. So I think there is another name for it.

Comment: Why does there have to be another name? What if this is a somewhat obscure thing to study, and that author is the only one who has done any online available research on them?

Comment: Because that's exactly what I'm wondering - if he is the only author.

Comment: There is a lot of research on 0/1 polytopes. E.g. there is a famous conjecture by Mihail and Vazirani about the mixing time of random walks on their graphs (given some extra assumptions). Note that these polytopes are the convex hulls of the indicator functions of some collection of subsets of a finite set, so they are interesting from the point of view of combinatorial optimization.

Answer (score 0):

At least those all are **hypercube facetings**.

--- rk